# Django empty a modal which contain an html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I am working with Django wherein I have a modal on a html page which includes the the html to be displayed when the modal is clicked. The modal is refreshed every 1 second until closed so as to get the latest data from the server. Now, when the modal is closed and clicked again for another link, the old data is still present and new data takes a second or two to be displayed. I want to know how we could empty the modal html before displaying the new data.

My modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" id="edit-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" id="close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 align="center" class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">IP details</h4>
        </div>
            <div id="cats" class="modal-body">
            {% include "ip_list.html" %}
            </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id ="close2" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Here ip_list.html is the html file which gets called when the modal is clicked.
Right below this I have my Jquery running to display the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
    var query;
    query = this.id;
    //console.log(query)
    $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
    $.get('/reserve/get/', {'ip': query}, function(data){
    $('#cats').html(data);
    //$('#edit-modal').modal('show');
    var handler = setInterval(function(){
    $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
    },1000);
    $('#close').button().click(function (){
            clearInterval(handler);
            //$('#edit-modal').modal('hide');

    });
    $('#close2').button().click(function (){
            clearInterval(handler);

    });
    $('body').click(function() {
            clearInterval(handler);
    });


 });


    //$('#edit-modal').modal('show');
});

});
</script>
```

Let me know if you need any other info. Any leads as to how I could achieve the empty HTML after the modal is closed is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add `$('#cats').html("");` to close button event.

Comment: I tried this. What happens is all the div elements are blank for that one second. I want the html to displayed with empty div values. It should display the label elements and not the actual value.